# Confusion regarding the implication of Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

From Liouville's theorem, we know that If a function $f$ is entire and bounded in the complex plane, then $f(z)$ is constant throughtout the plane

Is there a special meaning in the word constant? There are plenty of entire functions that have different values depending on different $z$. For example we know $sin(z)$ is entire and its range is not a single point. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The sine function is not bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sin(z)$ is not bounded in the complex plane.  Indeed, as we have
$$\sin(z) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz} - e^{-iz}),$$
it follows that $\sin(ix)$ (for $x \in \mathbb{R}$) grows exponentially as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I read it wrong, I thought the condition is bounded by the complex plane, not bounded in complex plane, thanks for the answer

Comment: No thanks are necessary, just click the check mark and the upward arrow :)